# oracle connection through jsp error

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor The Connection descriptor used by the client was: localhost:1521:XE

Iam getting this error in web page when i tried connection

this is my code

```js
Valid.jsp

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<body>
<%
String u=request.getParameter("t1");
String p=request.getParameter("t2");
if(u.equals("aptech") && p.equals("aptech"))
{ 


try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
out.println("Registered\n");
  Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","aptech");
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  out.println("Connected\n");
 PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?)" );
  pst.setString(1,u);
      pst.setString(2,p);
         pst.execute();
   out.println("Successfully Inserted Into Database");
}
catch(Exception e)
{

  out.println(e);
}



  
 }
else
{  
  
  out.println("Invalid Login");

}

%>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
Login.html
<html>
<body>
<form action="Valid.jsp">
UserName:<input type="text" name="t1">
Password:<input type="text" name="t2">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got XE defined as the **SID or SERVICE_NAME** for your connection in your **tnsnames.ora** file ? Also check alternative syntax for the connection string here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver . You could try a connection string like jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE

Comment: What happens if you type `sqlplus system/aptech@//localhost/XE` on the command prompt?